# Is there a deep learning method for 3D labels?

Tags: deep-learning, multilabel-classification, labels

As the question says, I want to feed labels into a neural net that are three dimensional. Let's say that I have 3 possible labels and each one of my data points corresponds to a percentage of those labels. e.g, my first datapoint contains 20% of label A, 30% of label B, and 50% of label C.

Is there any architecture able to deal with this shape of label data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the probability are summing up to zero, so you can simply treat it as *Multi-class problem and use a network with Softmax at the end*.

Last layer and compile -

> *model.add(keras.layers.Dense( 3, activation="softmax"))
>
> model.compile( optimizer='adam, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics='accuracy')*

**Metrics** - *Accuracy is not appropriate. Define a custom metrics based on the interpretation of 3 probabilities*

The labels will be as per the probability-

e.g. This is for MNIST 10 digits -

> **Digit 1** - *[0.05*, **0.55**, *0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05]*

> **Prediction** - *[0.064,* **0.356**, *0.059, 0.069, 0.068, 0.050, 0.044, 0.122, 0.064, 0.101]*

[**Code for MNIST - Colab link**](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AGgfmcCxJhzVg2RIbGHAtPKT7CGHJNwv)

Comment: Do you have a MNIST worked example with this label input that I could run??

Comment: Added in the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I can't accept the answer because I have low rep, but well, your solution works!

Comment: Reputation is for upvote not Accept. You should see a Green check